# Searching in large object arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a `Vuex.Store` where I have centralized all site data, this object is actually pretty big. In different pages, the user needs to search data while the result has to be paged.

In order to show all data, I partition a particular object array in my store in a way that I keep the `length` and `totalPages` in a component, and then iterate through the original array maintained by `Vuex`.

However, for searching, I have created an `action` in my `Vuex` module which takes an argument and compares items within the object array against that, and it finally returns a promise.

The actual problem is that, I then create a temporary array in my component for the searched items followed by re-assigning the `length` and `totalPages` values. I feel like this temporary array is something redundant which only increases the size of the DOM and I also feel like it is such a bad idea.

The point of posting this question is to know, whether this approach would be considered as a standard solution, or whether there are better ways for searching large repositories.

Comment: If your application is doing intensive operations I highly recommend looking into [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). They don't run on the main thread, meaning no blocking operations on your UI because they can't interact with the DOM. I use them to fetch chunks from APIs when the table is of any significant size.

Comment: This sounds like a flaw in your app design: the app should not store data in bulk. Perhaps what you want is for the app to store just a reference to each data point (e.g. an ID, or a page number), and whenever the data is required, your app makes an async request to the server/API which returns the full set of data. That also means your server can do all the heavy lifting of filtering/intersecting/joining the data as of when necessary.

Comment: @Terry: The purpose behind this is to load a blueprint of site content once (data size maxes out at 2MB) in order to smoothen user experience and minimize interaction with the server. Of course this data is just a text formatted in JSON containing only and only short text.

Comment: 2MB of data in a Vuex store seems to much to me.
I understand that you are tring to smoothen user experience but you shouldn't store all the information as it's unlikely that the user needs all that stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Let's take for example a simple blog.

We have the following pages:

/blog/page/1
/blog/page/4

/slug-of-the-post
/slug-of-another-post

My Vuex store has the following keys:

```
{
    posts: {},
    pages: {},
}
```

Now when the user goes to /blog/page/1 I fetch all the data for that page from the API and store each post in the posts object, and in the pages object I store only a reference to the post.
This is how the store looks like after going to /blog/page/1

```
{
    posts: {
        'blog-post-example': {
            id: 1,
            title: 'test'
        },
        'another-blog-post-example': {
            id: 2,
            title: 'another title'
        }

    },
    pages: {
        1: [
            'blog-post-example',
            'another-blog-post-example'
        ]
    },
}
```

Same happens if they go to the next page "/blog/page/2".

However, if they go back to "/blog/page/1", I can detect that the data of that page has already been fetched and I don't need to go back to the API.

This way you smoothen the UX, without loading all your blog posts into the store at once.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, the data blueprint as I explained maxes out at 2MG. If I wanted to fetch full data, the we'd be talking gigabytes which is out of the question. Your answer here is irrelevant, as it addresses a simple problem and of course it doesn't answer my question properly.

Comment: You post no code, you put a pretty hard to understand explanation only and even thougth I tried understanding your problem (which I failed at) you come here with this arrogant comment.

Add some code to the question and maybe someone wants to help.
Definetly not me

Comment: The question asks about a standard approach for reactive `searching` and not this. That's why I downvoted.

Comment: By the way, this solution that you have posted does not minimize communication with the server by any means. We have two different servers here, a web server and a file server, we include contents as links only in Vuex as a single of source of truth, and the file server will cache/serve requests.

Comment: What do you mean by minimize communication? It fetch the data only once, not sure how you can minimize it further..

Comment: And applying the search query from the user to the Vuex store makes little sense as you don't really know if all elements are present in Vuex or haven't been loaded.

I really don't understand how, why and what you try to acomplish if you don't post code.

Comment: Well, to break it down, we are developing a single page web panel, and that means all contents must be provided to the user. To clarify more, the only content that the user does not need is the information belonging to another user. What I am after is to fetch all metadata once at the time of login or upon a refresh request. Then I'd use this information to fetch relevant contents from the file server.The advantage is that when you wanna see a catalog for something, no Ajax post request to the server would be needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168421/discussion-between-borjante-and-arrrr).

Comment: This reduces stress on the main web server tremendously. But since the file server has been designed to tolerate heavy IO, there will be no issue with delivering the content such as Large Text, Audio, Video, Binaries, etc.